# What are the possible ways of storing web contents ( images,videos,pdf etc)?

Tags: image, web, cdn

We are planning to host one web app which uses multiple resources like banner images, videos, pdf and they need to be changed by time. If we package those resources in app, app size will get increased and in every change we need to repackage and redeploy.

So we have planned to have aws S3 and cloudFront cdn for serving all static web content and we can use them in application.

Please suggest pros and cons of our architecture and other possible ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. **AWS S3** is indeed a very good choice for hosting your static assets.
As stated by AWS itself :

> S3 is a highly durable, highly available, and inexpensive object
>   storage service that can serve stored objects directly via HTTP. This
>   makes it **wonderfully useful for serving static web content** directly to
>   web browsers for sites on the Internet.

What does your "app" do? Is it just to display static content? Or does it have a solid backend? 
Since it is unclear, to get started, here is a wonderful resource from the official AWS site : 
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-modern-app-fargate-lambda-dynamodb-python/ 
They have clearly explained how to host your static content and structure your web app.

The pros of using AWS S3 are that it's really cheap, easy to use and configure.
Cons are ,IF you are just hosting static content, you will be charged for it.Why not use Github pages? It's entirely free!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Azure Blob storage. You may store any file format and it can be secured with a security token for restricted access. It scales without limit and is considered a best practice for large volume web traffic. Hope it helps.